# Regex to match md5 hashes

Tags: php, regex, match

What type of regex should be used to match a md5 hash.

how to validate this type of string `00236a2ae558018ed13b5222ef1bd987`

i tried something like this:  `('/^[a-z0-9]/')` but it didnt work.

how to achieve this? thanks

Comment: If you're given a string and you want to validate it as md5, simply check for length 32 and characters a-f0-9.

Comment: By "validate", do you simply mean that any 32-character string containing only valid hexadecimal digits will pass?

Comment: For instance with `[[:xdigit:]]` and a repetition of `{32}` enclosed in start and end markers.

Comment: the `f` letter was the problem. thanks

Comment: The simplicity of the question - The [first search result](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+validate+hash) on Google happens to be a duplicate on this very site... as a general rule of thumb: if you get an immediate answer, you probably didn't put enough effort into the question.

Comment: @Emissary omg now i see. sorry

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is a PCRE that will match a MD5 hash:

```
define('R_MD5_MATCH', '/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/i');

if(preg_match(R_MD5_MATCH, $input_string)) {
    echo "It matches.";
} else {
    echo "It does not match.";
}
```

Comment: Beware of hashes with upper-case literals. Both upper and lower case are valid so eliminating the one or the other is not correct. The regex should probably look like this: `'/^[a-fA-F0-9]{32}$/i'`. Cheers.

Comment: @el.nicko I'm trying to understand ...since the regex includes `i` for case-insensitive, why specify both `a-f` and `A-F`?   Do you have any links to back-up/expand-upon your point?

Comment: @el.nicko this wouldn't matter because it's got the `i` modifier. The reason only the lowercase range is there and not both is because of the `i` modifier.

Comment: ACK, you've got a point there. In the context of the question and the given answer you are 100% correct. There are some setups though (e.g. java) where the `i` won't work or at least not as expected, but adding the upper and lower case works and enhances readability depending on how one sees it :-)

Comment: These are PCRE's . How Java does it is not relevant. Regular Expressions aren't always portable across engines.

Comment: It works, but worth noting is that it will match any hexadecimal string of 32 characters. 
eg.
$input_string=bin2hex(random_bytes(16));

Basically, since md5 hash is actual hexadecimal string, there is really no way to check if string truly is md5.

Answer (score 10):

Try [`ctype_xdigit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-xdigit.php):

```
<?php

$hash = '00236a2ae558018ed13b5222ef1bd987';

var_dump(strlen($hash) === 32 && ctype_xdigit($hash));
```

[Output](http://3v4l.org/UIlFJ): `bool(true)`

Comment: I prefer this one onto `preg_match`.

Comment: It's actually also faster than regex. 

It could be also put inside a function (eg isHash(string $hash, int $length = 32), for a small cost of function call overhead. Even that way is probably still faster than regex. 

Worth noting: It matches any 32-char hexadecimal string. There is no way to explicitly validate md5.