# Easy way to disinguish one hash type from another

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to find a simple way to distinguish between output of various cryptographic hash functions, such as `MD5`, `RIPEMD`, `SHA`, `Whirlpool`, and also, to tell them from SHA2 and Blowfish-based scheme algos, for example, `Bcrypt`.

While it's quite easy to check that hash is looks like, say, `MD5`, by `PCRE` or simple lenght check with `ctype_xdigit()` ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517102/regex-to-match-md5-hashes)), `Bcrypt` requires a bit more of a thought.

There is lots of hash outputs I need to check. I'm trying to find simple solution or library to accomplish it - maybe someone knows something.

*P.S.:* Also, as far as I can see, not all hashes *could* be verified, and that bothers me as well.

Comment: As any cryptographic hash string should 'look like' a random string, i am not sure how you could determine the algorithm that generated it by just looking at the output. It may be useful to explain why you want to do this?

Comment: Well, it's not just a random string, major ones are different. *MD5* is `1bc29b36f623ba82aaf6724fd3b16718`, *SHA1* is `ba79baeb9f10896a46ae74715271b7f586e74640`, *Bcrypt* is `$2y$10$KssILxWNR6k62B7yiX0GAe2Q7wwHlrzhF3LqtVvpyvHZf0MwvNfVu` - length is different, encoding scheme is different... I need it as part of my research work.